# How to make Manipulate slider animation controls larger font?

Tags: manipulate

I am giving a presentation with several `Manipulate`s and I would like to enlarge the animation control font size.  By default it's quite small.  For example, the code:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a z], {z, -1, 1}], {a, -1, 1}]
```

when the animation control is selected, gives the value of `"a"` in a small font size.

I can't seem to figure out how to enlarge the font for this and I was wondering if someone could help me.

Thanks
Dominic

Comment: You can do it with `BaseStyle` thus: `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a z], {z, -1, 1}], {a, -1, 1, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}}]`. But the input field does not resize to show the whole text of the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[a z], {z, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> Framed[StringForm["a=``", a]], 
  LabelStyle -> 16], {{a, -1, Style["a", 16]}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  But that only changes the font size for the label "a"  What I would like to do is change the font size for the value of "a" when the user presses the animation control button.

Comment: You can show it with the plot. Check the new answer.

Comment: That's it guys.  Thanks.  Nice code!  You guys have been a big help here helping me get my presentation ready for the tech conference next week.  Will remember to acknowledge your help.  This really is the place to get what I think is first-class help in Mathematica! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default value of the option `DefaultLabelStyle`:

```
Options[Manipulate, DefaultLabelStyle]
```

> {DefaultLabelStyle -> "ManipulateLabel"}

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "ManipulateLabel"}]
```

> {ShowStringCharacters -> False, NumberMarks -> False,
>        FontFamily :> CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"],
>        FontSize :> CurrentValue["PanelFontSize"] - 1, FontWeight -> "Plain"}

Define your new style

```
newDefaultLabelStyle = {ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
   NumberMarks -> False, FontFamily :> "Old English Text MT", 
   FontSize :> CurrentValue["PanelFontSize"] + 10, 
   FontWeight -> "Plain"};

Row[{Manipulate[Plot[Sin[ABCDEF  z], {z, -1, 1}], {ABCDEF, -1, 1}], 
  Manipulate[Plot[Sin[ABCDEF z], {z, -1, 1}], {ABCDEF, -1, 1}, 
   DefaultLabelStyle -> newDefaultLabelStyle]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for *not* using Comic Sans as your example font.

Comment: @bob, not that i didn't think about it:)